# Create global temporary table within stored procedures in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, temporary-objects

I am an experienced SQL Server programmer but new to Oracle. I want to write a stored procedure. The first thing I want to do is to create a *Global Temporary Table*, which I will then populate and finally return the results (I have done this many times in SQL Server).

Here's the skeleton of what I have. Oracle complains. Can somebody tell me why and what to do about it? (I have created a Global Temporary Table outside of the stored procedure and it works as expected)

Thanks,

Dick

```
create or replace PROCEDURE usp_MU_Secure_Msg_Rpt (startdate IN varchar2, enddate IN varchar2)

IS

BEGIN

CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE Denominator_pvids

(pvid number (38,0),

searchname varchar2 (78),

no_distinct_pids integer,

no_secure_messages integer)

ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;


--SQL to populate table goes here


SELECT * FROM Denominator_pvids


END;
```

Comment: As an aside, while temporary tables are very common in SQL Server, they are very uncommon in Oracle.  Although you can create a global temporary table and use that in Oracle, you'll probably be happier if you avoid temporary tables in Oracle.  You may want a PL/SQL collection instead, you may just want a view.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192774/alternative-for-a-mysql-temporary-table-in-oracle/7193529#7193529

Answer (score 4):

any `CREATE TABLE` statement is a DDL, which cannot be used within a PL/SQL block (exception: dynamic sql - but you don't need that here).

What you should do is CREATE the (Global Temp) table ahead of time, just like a permanent table. Have it created by the DBA first - up front.

You can then access it / populate it, truncate it .. whatever you want ... within the procedure just fine.  (although TRUNCATE would need dynamic SQL, and probably isn't needed - but depends on how you're using it, really)

The advantage of a global temporary table is that the data in it is accessible only to your session.  The table itself, however, should be there - always - from the start.

As a devil's advocate. Let's assume you use dynamic SQL to `CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE` within your routine.

Now consider what happens when 2 people call your routine at the same time ...
(they both try to create the same table!  O.o  oops).

So yes, have your DBA create it up front first .  You can then INSERT/UPD/DEL as you wish from it.

Here's an example of 1 being used.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables

Comment: temp tables in oracle are not exactly like SQL server.  As @Ditto said, you create one time.